# How can I get Device token to send notification?

Tags: php, firebase, codeigniter, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

I have built web version in Codeigniter and have been working in mobile version with react Native.
To make new order notification, I am going to use firebase clouding message.
how , where can I get this device token ?

```
public function sendFCMNotification($registration_ids, $message){

        $SERVER_API_KEY ='my server api key';
        // payload data, it will vary according to requirement
        $data = [
            "registration_ids" => $registration_ids, 
            "data" => $message
        ];
        $dataString = json_encode($data);
    
        $headers = [
            'Authorization: key=' . $SERVER_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ];
    
        $ch = curl_init();
      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);
               
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
      
        curl_close($ch);
      
        return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your React-Native app, you can get the token like this:

messaging().getToken().then(token => { saveTokenToDatabase(token);});

then listen for any token change

messaging().onTokenRefresh(token => {saveTokenToDatabase(token);});

The method saveTokenToDatabase is used to save the token to your backend so that you can access it later to send messages

Answer (score 0):

In android you need to use this class to get device token

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
    super.onNewToken(token);
    Log.e("newToken", token);
    //Add your token in your sharefpreferences.
    SharedPreferenceManager app_sp = new SharedPreferenceManager(this);
    app_sp.putString(Constants.FIREBASE_TOKEN, token);
```

this service request which update device token on to your server
//        updatetokenAPI.updateToken(token);